# ViewBag aparece na view em branco

Tags: mvc, controller, view

Tenho esse codigo na controller, onde faço alguns tratamentos e retorno os valores.

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage ListarHora()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.totalHorasDisponiveis = "teste";
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        
    }
```

Já testei e a controller esta trazendo corretamente os valores, porem ao enviar a View, a ViewBag não mostra nada.

```
<div class="form-group" id="horasdisponiveis">
            <label>3º - Selecione o(s) horario(s) que deseja reservar:</label>
            <label id="Total" value="@ViewBag.totalHorasDisponiveis" />
        </div>
```

Aqui seque o html

```
<div class="form-group" id="horasdisponiveis">
            <label>3º - Selecione o(s) horario(s) que deseja reservar:</label>
            <label id="Total"></label></div>
```

O que poderia ser ?

Answer (score 0):

Segundo informações que obtive com outros analistas, NÃO é possível usar Viewbag em partialView que não efetua um Load.

Vou utilizar um return partialView()! Assim que conseguir, publico minha solução para quem estiver com a mesma duvida.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solução que aprendi e gostaria de repassar foi a seguinte:

1º Na Controller tenho o código abaixo:
Onde eu recebo uma lista de horas por meio retorno do validardataplateia e "envio" para minhapartialview através do metodo return PartialView colocando o nome da view e a lista que quero passar.

```
public ActionResult ListarHora(AgendaEstudio parametro)
    {
            List<AgendaEstudio> ListaHorasDisponiveis = AgendamentoNegocio.ValidarDataPlateia(parametro);
            return PartialView("_PartialListarHora", ListaHorasDisponiveis);
        
    }
```

2ºNa minha partial view eu tenho o código abaixo:
Aqui ainda não é minha view principal onde vou exibir os dados !!!
Aqui é apenas minha partial view...ou seja um pedaço da minha pagina.

```
   @using See.Sed.AgendaCMSP.Lib.Entidade
   @model List<AgendaEstudio>
```

E para trazer meu checkbox ainda na partial view eu uso o seguinte código (FOR):

```
<div class="searchable-container">
                        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                        {

                            <div class="items col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                <div class="info-block block-info clearfix">
                                    <div class="square-box pull-left">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                                            <div class="bizcontent">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id=@Model[i].hora_evento value=@Model[i].id_hora_estudio>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                                <h5>@Model[i].hora_evento</h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
```

3º - E por fim na minha View principal em uma determinada DIV eu insiro o código:
abaixo:

```
<div class="form-group" >
                <label>3º - Selecione o(s) horario(s) que deseja reservar:</label>
                <div id="horasdisponiveis"></div>
            </div>
```

Onde o nome "horasdisponiveis" vai fazer vinculo ao AJAX abaixo, porque eu quero que essa lista apareça apenas quando eu clicar em uma determinada data: (codigo abaixo)

```
function CarregarHoras() {
    var parametro = {
        plateia_sala: document.querySelector("#plateia_sala").value,
        data_evento: document.querySelector("#data_evento").value
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ListarHora", "Agendamento")',
        data: parametro,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#horasdisponiveis").html(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Observe que em success (retorno de sucesso lá da controller) eu exibo os meus dados utilizando:

```
$("#horasdisponiveis").html(data);
```

Valeu !!!